# How to use multiple field calculator in QGIS graphical modeler

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

I find myself struggling to understand how to chain field calculator process in the graphical modeler in QGIS.
I have build a model that take 3 layers input and 3 vector field parameters and try to make some calculation with the field calculator, 3 time one after another. I stuck in the first one and the thirdץ
The first take pre-calculte value (choose the field name from the parcels layer in the start of the model), and calculate the concatenation of the numeric fields "GUSH" and "PARCEL", with the "_" sign between them = "1000_10" for example.

```
concat(to_string(@SelectGushField) || '_' || to_string(@SelectParcelField))
```

the second calculator calculate the area, as name "Calc_Area" (which not show in the next field calculator)

```
$area
```

the third calculate the ratio between the legal area of the parcel and the calculate area of the same feature

```
  @SelectLegalArea / @add_calc_area_field_OUTPUT
```

this calculate is also not working

[image]
[image]
[image]

using QGIS 3.16.1 on Windows

Can someone explain to me how to solve this?

Comment: Why is "add ratio" calculation based on a vanilla layer instead of only the output of the other calculations?

Comment: how I should do it if I just want to add a new field and calculate something? I know its unnecessary.

Comment: I think it'd be useful to know what your "select XY" algorithms do exactly, as well as how you original data looks like.

Comment: I didnt use any selection. if you ask what is my goal, so i want to  add those fields and calculation before i start clip the parcel layer with the other layers.

Comment: Then why are there three yellow rectangles named "selection XY"?

Comment: they select the fields from the parcels layer, with those  fields i do the calc.
"GUSH_NUM" + '_' + "PARCEL_NUM" => "1000_10" for the key field
"LEGAL_AREA" / "CALC_AREA" => for the ratio field

Comment: So you do run a selection. Since this seems to be rather complex, I strongly suggest you update your post with all the necessary details, especially some example data, what each step in your model (should) do(es) and your desired output.